# How do you make a dynamic number of circles orbit around a text in a React component?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

After every 5 seconds my React Component hits an API, which in result provides me a list of items.

In sass, I would like to create circles as equal to the number of items I am getting and then make them orbit around a text.

These items basically represent a list of online devices in my application.

Here is the code that shows the text I would like the circles to orbit around:

```
<div className="devices-online">{this.state.devices.length}</div>
<div className="devices-label">
    <p>Devices</p> 
    <p>Online</p>
</div>
```

The number of circles should be equal to:
    this.state.devices.length

So the circles should orbit around the above text that reads: "{this.state.devices.length} Devices Online".

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve something like this with css animations and classes.

*This animation* is a little more elaborate than what you're looking for, but could be modified/simplified for your use case. https://codepen.io/belal-mrb/pen/dvBgOP

You could render an element for each circle with a css class for the animation, something like this:

```
<div>
    {new Array({this.state.devices.length}).map(i => 
        <div key={i} className="circle custom-animation-class" />)}
</div>
```